# Allow only number in a ion-input with type=text Ionic

Tags: validation, input, ionic3, angular5

I need to make the following input so it accepts only numbers:

```
<ion-input formControlName="quantity"></ion-input>
```

I know this can be achieved with type=number but I'm restricted to using the type text for other reasons. Is it possible to do so with type text? And also how could I validate a min and max amount?

Comment: if i understand it correct, you are willing to restrict user input using Angular/Any other JS based restrictions right??

Comment: correct, Ionic in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do the trick with a keypress event in TypeScript file and only authorize numbers …
In the listener, you can preventDefault the event, stop its propoagation and return false when it's not a digit

Answer (score 6):

It can be done precisely in following way:

**In your .ts file:**

```
numericOnly(event): boolean {
   let pattern = /^([0-9])$/;
   let result = pattern.test(event.key);
   return result;
}
```

**In your .html file:**

```
<ion-input
        class="input"
        inputmode="numeric"
        type="number"
        (keypress)="numericOnly($event)"
      >
</ion-input>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `component.html`:

```
`<ion-input (ionInput)="onInput($event)" maxlength="3" ></ion-input>`
```

And then in your `component.ts` file:

```
onInput($event:any) {
 let theEvent = $event || window.event,
     key = theEvent.target.value,
     regex = /[0-9]+/g
 if( !regex.test(key) ) {
   let resp = $event.target.value.match(regex)
   $event.target.value = resp ? resp.join('')  : ''
 }
}
```

Just prune out anything that isn't a number from the value when input is detected.

Answer (score 1):

**In your html file**

```
<ion-input (ionInput)="numeric($event)" formControlName="quantity"></ion-input>
```

**In Your ts file**

```
numeric(event){
   let patter = /^([0-9])$/;
   let val = pattern.test(event.key);
   return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

---

I know it's not for input type="text". But it solves the Number Only problem.

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>Number</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="tel" maxlength="10"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Refer this link: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/7072#issuecomment-301675025

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: type="tel" allowing characters that are not numbers